# I have a textarea that won't have 100% in width when I set it in CSS or plain HTML?

Tags: html, css

How can I set a textarea to 100% in width? it dosn't work when I say: textarea {width: 100%} in css.

Comment: Seems to work in IE and Firefox. Got any code or additional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It does work](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/zdVZC/) but a parent element is probably just restricting the width of your `<textarea>` so without seeing your code there's no specific answer to your question.

Comment: friendsconnect.org/dashboard/dashboard.html If you look at it now, do you know why the textarea seems to be longer than the parent DIV? I set the two textareas to 100% but they go outside the div? Why should I be doing differently

Comment: @Pete Allport: Adding padding and border to the `<textarea>` makes it wider than 100%. You'll need to give it an absolute value like `418px` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to fix this issue:

- Give the parent element a `padding-right` equal to the accumulated border-width and padding of the textarea (supported by all browsers)
- Use the `box-sizing` property to include border and padding when setting width:

  ```
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  ```

  (supported by IE8+ and all other browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of the parent elements have an appropriate width - post more information if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting a semi-column:

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's not required for the last rule. See pretty much every answer I've written on this site.

Comment: @thirtydot: this does not make a difference here, but I disagree: even though it is totally not required, it *is* good style, making maintenance a bit easier (unless you're optimising bytes). (Although I'm the last one to talk, I often omit curlies on one-line `if` statements *blush* )

Comment: @Amadan: It depends on how you look at it; because I always omit that last semicolon, I'm always aware, so it doesn't affect the difficulty of maintenance *for me* in the slightest, whether I'm looking at CSS that is omitting it or not. ;)

Comment: friendsconnect.org/dashboard/dashboard.html If you look at it now, do you know why the textarea seems to be longer than the parent DIV? I set the two textareas to 100% but they go outside the div? Why should I be doing differently