# How to set textarea to 100% width and height?

Tags: html, css, textarea

How can i set a `<textarea>` to consume 100% width and height of the browser window?

For example, the following does not work:

```css
html, body, textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Text goes here</textarea>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upv7y7qr/)

Because it consumes slightly over 100% of the window, causing a scrollbar to appear:

[image]

How do i make a `<textarea>` consume 100% of the space?

### Bonus Reading

- [How to set width and height of textarea](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/406248/How-to-set-width-and-height-of-textarea)
- [How to set a Textarea to 100% height in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261851)
- [I want to set the height of a TextArea to 100% of a Table Cell in XHTML 1.0 Transitional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363135)
- [I have a textarea that won't have 100% in width when I set it in CSS or plain HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445948)
- [How can I make a TextArea 100% width without overflowing when padding is present in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271067)
- [Textarea to fill a parent container exactly, with padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795981)
- [How to have a textarea at 100% width and keep its margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313664)
- [100% textarea problem](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/100-textarea-problem/2547)

Comment: Would absolute positioning on the textarea work for you? `textarea {
position:absolute;
}` seems to do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work. or just add `display:block` to textarea in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upv7y7qr/2/).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the [common white space issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952703/8620333) of `inline-block`/`inline` element due to vertical alignment. If you check dev tools of google you will see this:

[image]

So to fix it you simply need to adjust vertical alignment or make the textarea a block element (like provided in the other answers):

```css
html, body, textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
textarea {
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Text goes here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
  resize:none;/*Add this if you dont want users to resize */
}
```

```html
<textarea>Text goes here</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove width and height for html and body tag.

Thank me later